# WPF: Double Click on Path Event

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, path

I have several paths nested inside a canvas.  I want each path to display a MessageBox when the user double clicks on the path.  I know the path class doesn't have the MouseDoubleClick event, but the canvas class does so maybe that can help.

How do you create a MouseDoubleClick event for a Path?

Comment: Does the `Path.MouseLeftButtonDown` event not contain the appropriate `ClickCount` on the event args?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: A lot of people do not know that this property exists.

Comment: @H.B.: agreed, but I didn't feel it was good enough to stand alone as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Path` class has the `MouseDown` event. You can detect the number of clicks with the `ClickCount` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs`.

Check http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event for more info.